# Server migration - how to debug undelivered emails from a single sender

Tags: email, migration

We're recently migrated to a new server, and I've just noticed that we're no longer receiving emails from one particular sender.  All other emails are being delivered ok.

It's been 60 hours since the nameservers were updated and it only took an hour or so for the other emails to be redirected correctly.

I am trying to access the sender's logs, but I'm not sure if we'll be able to access these because the emails are being sent from an automated 3rd party service, and their customer service are not being very responsive.

I am unsure how to go about debugging this. So my question is:

*What technical issues may be causing emails from a single sender to go AWOL? Is there anything under my control (ie. on our own server) that I could investigate to see why this is happening?*

Answer (score 0):

We managed to get a look at the bounce message for the email.

Their emails were still being sent to the old IP address, so it looks like there was some caching somewhere down the line.

But I'm not sure where.

It's now well over 3 days since the nameservers were updated, so I'm surprised they haven't updated by now.

I expect it is DNS caching on their mailserver. If anybody can shed more light I'd be interested.